# How to use the entire Hard disk for use in Ubuntu 20.04(fresh installation)?

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, 20.04, hard-drive

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04. While installing I chose the option to `Erase the Entire Disk` so that all the previous installed OS's will also get removed.

But now after installation, what I see is that I have only 5.7gb free space as I have shown in the screenshot.

[image]

When I tried to check my disks using `Disks` app, you can see that it shows 2 disks. I thought there will be only one disk having the whole size of 1TB there since I erased the entire disk while installation.

I used `Gparted` to allocate the unallocated space of 1000gb and mounted it. But it still shows the same free space of 5.7gb.

[image]

Also, here is the partition list ie the output of `sudo parted -l`.
[image]

Edit: This was the warning I was shown when I went with the default option. I didnt get to choose the partition since I selected the first option so I thought it will choose the biggest partition automatically. Also, I didnt create any kind pf partitions so I am not sure why is it showing 2 partitions and got installed in the other partition?

[image]

Can anyone please help me with this so I can use the entire disk for my use? I am not sure if I made any mistake during the installation part as I just went with the default options. I have tried installing Ubuntu twice by erasing the entire disk but I am unable to fix this problem.

P.S: I am not trying to dual boot. I just want Ubuntu as the only OS on my laptop.

Thanks in advance,
john400

Comment: It looks like you installed to a wrong disk that is 14.4 GB. Or you are running from a liveusb. Did you reboot after you installed the system?

Comment: No I have already installed it(not using liveusb). @Pilot6, will you kindly check my edits? I can also do a fresh install if it's somewhat easy but what should I keep in mind while doing that? I have already done fresh installations twice

Comment: You have a 14 GB SSD and a 1TB HDD. You installed to the first one. It is OK. You can use both disks.

Comment: And you installed it twice. One time on each disk ;-)

Comment: Can you please tell me what should I do now? I am only getting 6gb free space actually. Should I do a fresh install? And if yes, how should I make it choose the hdd partition while installing?

Comment: You can do lots of things, e.g. boot from your HDD using another Ubuntu option in boot menu. It seems that you have installed it on both disks. It is too broad to tell.

Comment: Unplug the disk you don't want and install to the disk you do. Then format the disk you don't want.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get it work. I tried to do a fresh install by deleting all the partitions. Then I created a swap, efi and a ext4 partition on the hdd and installed the OS on ext4. Its working properly now. :)